# Upgrade to Birt 2.3.1 and log SEVERE: Not allowed choice any

Tags: reporting, report, birt

After an upgrade to BIRT 2.3.1 have a tons of logs:

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.model.metadata.ChoicePropertyType validateXml
SEVERE: Not allowed choice any
```

Any thoughts how to rid of them will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. During the upgrade to 2.3.1 you have to rid of from links to **"any"** data types in all BIRT files.

IMO the simplest way is to delete all strings like below from *.rptdesign files.

```
<property name="dataType">any</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message in BIRT 2.5 for this situation is

```
SEVERE: not found choice: any
```

Very confusing, but the first answer is helpful.